# Passing options with render partials and checking for them inside those partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to set some options for some render partials and then check against them inside those partials. How to achieve something like the below?

### Pseudo code:

**views/articles/show.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: "shared/info", locals: { from_apples: true } %>
<%= render partial: "shared/info", locals: { from_bananas: true } %>
```

**views/shared/_info.html.erb**

```
<% if from_apples %>
  <p>Foo</p>
<% elsif from_bananas %>
  <p>Bar</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `local_assigns`:

```
<% if local_assigns[:from_apples] %>
  <p>Foo</p>
<% elsif local_assigns[:from_bananas] %>
  <p>Bar</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create two partial one for apples and one for bananas. instead of passing locals call those partial files.

```
<%= render partial: "shared/info/apples" %>
<%= render partial: "shared/info/bananas" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

why not pass the data in?

```
<%= render partial: "shared/info", locals: { message: "foo" } %>
<%= render partial: "shared/info", locals: { message: "bar" } %>
```

views/shared/_info.html.erb

```
<p><%= message %></p>
```